# filter an array based on selected dropdown item -redux-react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have a dropdownlist. Based on selected dropdown item i have to display currency. Here is the data structure : **[{mruCode: "1700", country: "US", countryText: "United States", division: "WORLDWIDE_INDUSTRIAL",currency:"USD"}....]**. I mapped this data to my select item. Now based on selected item (ex: division: "WorldWIDE_Industrial") i have to show currency(ex. "USD") in a label. If dropdown value change then onChange event will fire and display the corresponding currency.

I have created the action and reducer for this and filter the list based onChange action fire. I am not able to understand how to handle the change event. Please help on this.

component code:

```
class LocationList extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            isLoading:false,
        };

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      this.props.loadData();
    }

    handleChange(mruCode){
      this.props.currencyLists(mruCode);
    }

    render(){
      const{location}=this.props;
      console.log(this.props.currList);
      const _labels = store.getLabels();
        return(<div>
            <span className="btnElement_spacing">You are viewing pricing for </span> 
  //here is the problem start i assume
             <select id="toggleLocationName">
                                  {location.map((item,index) =>
                   <option  key={index} onChange={()=>this.handleChange(item.mruCode)}> value={index}>{_labels[item.division]}</option> 
                    )}
          </select> 
          <span className="btnElement_spacing"> in </span>
                  {this.props.currList.map((item,index)=><label id="toggle-currency" key ={index}>{item.currency}</label>)}
            </div>
             );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
      location: state.locationRed.location,
      currList: state.locationRed.currList
    }
  }

  const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
      loadData:()=>{dispatch(loadData())},
      currencyLists:(mruCode)=>{dispatch(currencyLists(mruCode))}
      }
    }


  export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(LocationList);
```

action code:

```
export const currencyLists = mruCode =>({
  type: CURRENCY_LIST,
  payload: mruCode
});
```

reducer code:

```
case 'CURRENCY_LIST':
        let newState = Object.assign({}, state)
        let newCurrList = newState.location.filter((el) => el.mruCode === action.mruCode)
        return Object.assign({}, newState, {
            currList: newCurrList
        });
```

i am trying to filter out the main list based on mruCode with action id for onChange and saved the result into a currList. mapped to display the currency. But i am failed. currList initially showing empty. onChange not triggered. How to make action fire to show the currency

Comment: As the object is passed with data('mruCode') stored in key 'payload'.Try changing `let newCurrList = newState.location.filter((el) => el.mruCode === action.mruCode)` to `let newCurrList = newState.location.filter((el) => el.mruCode === action.payload) `. It should work.

Comment: yes i have tried. But, currList is showing empty. because onChange is not firing. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Onchange should be called on select tag(not on option tag). Below code should work.

```
<select id="toggleLocationName" onChange={this.handleChange}>
  {location.map((item, index) =>
    <option key={index} value={item.mruCode}>{_labels[item.division]}</option>
  )}
</select>

handleChange(e){
  this.props.currencyLists(e.target.value);
}
```